# Convert PHP $text into clickable url link on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a script to my functions.php file in WordPress to generate additional text in the Woocommerce Thank-You page.

```
 **
* Custom text on the receipt page.
*/
function isa_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
$new = $text . ' A receipt has been sent to you via email.Please submit your ticket here:https://google.com';
return $new;
}
```

Part of the text is a link to another page.

`Please submit your ticket here:https://google.com';`

However, the link does not display as a highlighted/clickable URL on the frontend. How do I fix this?

Comment: `<a href="">` ... ?

Comment: With basic HTML? `<a href="...">...</a>`?

Comment: oops! What an idiot! Sometimes I amaze myself! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a link inside your PHP string :
`$new = $text . ' A receipt has been sent to you via email.Please submit your ticket <a href="https://google.com">here</a>';`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 **
* Custom text on the receipt page.
*/
function isa_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
$new = $text . ' A receipt has been sent to you via email.Please submit your ticket <a href="https://google.com">here</a>';
return $new;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$new = $text . ' A receipt has been sent to you via email.Please submit your ticket <a href="https://google.com">here (https://google.com)</a>';
return $new;
```

Comment: What's the reason for -1?